# Implement Generic Power Function Without Using Math.pow in Java

Tags: java

I want to write a program in java, which will perform a number raised to a power, but without using math.pow. The program should be generic to include fractions as well.
The loop increment method will increment by 1, which is okay for integers; but not fractions. Please Suggest a generic method that would be helpful to me.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Is it homework?

Comment: "Without" is a tag?  Holy crap.

Comment: @Mark Peters: But just with 26 tagged questions.

Comment: (a/b)^x = pow(a,x) / pow(b,x).  I wouldn't worry too much about fractions, unless of course this is homework...

Answer (score 4):

First, observe that pow(a,x) = exp(x * log(a)).

You can implement your own exp() function using the [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) expansion for 
e<sup>x</sup>:

e<sup>x</sup> = 1 + x + x<sup>2</sup>/2! + x<sup>3</sup>/3! + x<sup>4</sup>/4! + x<sup>5</sup>/5! + ...

This will work for non-integer values of x.  The more terms you include, the more
accurate the result will be.

Note that by using some algebraic identities, you only need to resort to the series expansion for x in the range 0 < x < 1 .  exp(int + frac) = exp(int)*exp(frac), and there's no need to use a series expansion for exp(int). (You just multiply it out,
since it's an integer power of *e*=2.71828...).

Similarly, you can implement log(x) using one of these series expansions:

log(1+x) = x - x<sup>2</sup>/2 + x<sup>3</sup>/3 - x<sup>4</sup>/4 + ...

or

log(1-x) = -1 * (x + x<sup>2</sup>/2 + x<sup>3</sup>/3 + x<sup>4</sup>/4 + ...  )

But these series only converge for x in the interval -1 < x < 1.  So for values
of **a** outside this range, you might have to use the identity

log(pq) = log(p) + log(q)

and do some repeated divisions by *e* (= 2.71828...) to bring **a** down into a range where
the series expansion converges.  For example, if a=4, you'd have to take take x=3
to use the first formula, but 3 is outside the range of convergence. So we start
dividing out factors of e:

4/e = 1.47151...

log(4) = log(e*1.47151...) = 1 + log(1.47151...)

Now we can take x=.47151..., which *is* within the range of convergence, and evaluate log(1+x) using the series expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what a power function should do.

Mathematically: x^5 = x * x * x * x * x, or ((((x*x)*x)*x)*x)

Within your for loop, you can use the *= operator to achieve the operation that happens above.

How are you handling fractions? Java has no built-in fraction type; it stores decimals that would calculate the same way as integers (in other words, x * x works with both types). If you have a special class for fractions, your loop just needs two steps: one to multiply the numerator and one to multiply the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

While reading up on powers on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation):

```
a^x = exp( x ln(a) ) for any real number x
```

Is this cheating?